# Always need to renew ssh-keys working with Bitbucket from two machines

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've never had any problems working with my repos hosted on Bitbucket using SSH connection with a generated keypair. But since I'm accessing my repos from two different machines (e.g. home machine, work machine), I always get

```
Permission denied (publickey).fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

everytime I switch machines. So my current not so great workaround is to delete my current key with

```
rm -r .ssh
```

(I'm just using one) and then generate a new one, either using Sourcetree or Terminal. Then I remove the old key for the machine I'm using from my Bitbucket Account and paste in the new key.

This has been working since, but there has to be a better solution. I've browsed the Bitbucket docs, but it just says to add a new key for every machine, which is accessing the repos and obviously this it not working. I'm sure I'm missing something. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried adding multiple keys to your account?

Comment: So is this macOS Sierra or macOS High Sierra? Does `ssh-add -L` list your keys?

Comment: Both machines are currently running on High Sierra. The output of the command is `The agent has no identities.` Is it supposed to be like this? Seems like I have to add the keys manually after I've generated them, this might be the problem...

Comment: So I've tracked down the issue and its not caused by Bitbucket but both machines. When I generate a key either through Sourcetree or Terminal, the key is removed from the ssh list after I restart the machine, even if I add the key manually with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. When I type `ssh-add -L` after restart, it returns `The agent has no identities.`. Any ideas, why the key is removed and how to fix it?

Comment: forgot to mention @JimRedmond

Comment: Apple changed how ssh-agent works in Sierra, and they've kept the change in High Sierra (and will probably keep it in future versions as well). You should be able to add `AddKeysToAgent yes` to the Bitbucket segment of your ~/.ssh/config, along with the usual `IdentityFile /path/to/private/key` part; this should automatically add the relevant key(s) to your ssh-agent, where they'll persist until your next reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JimRedmond! The content of my `~/.ssh/config` seems to already be generated correctly by Sourcetree (`AddKeysToAgent yes`, `IdentityFile *points to private key*`) but the problem persists... Any idea?

Comment: Tried using `ssh-add -K *path to private key*` to store the key in Keychain with `UseKeychain yes` in `~/.ssh/config`, still gone after reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a link to a guide on how to fix that problem.

https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain

As described in the comments, Apple changed SSH behavior in Sierra/High Sierra. Theres a Sourcetree issue with status 'resolved' about this topic (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-4499), so Sourcetree adds keys to `.ssh/config` with the needed flags since 2.7.2 but still this hasn't worked for me. I needed to add `ssh-add -A`to my launch agents.

Answer (score 1):

You should add ssh keys both from your home machine and work machine into your bitbucket account.

The whole steps to add ssh keys to bitbucket as below (you can skip the steps which you have already done):

1. **Generate SSH Key in home machine**

   In your home machine, execute `ssh-keygen` command. And it will generate ssh key in your local machine. Copy the content of the public key `id_rsa.pub` to add it in bitbucket (as step2 shows).
2. **Add the ssh key from home machine to bitbucket**

   In bitbucket home page -> Bitbucket settings (https://bitbucket.org/account/user/username) -> SSH keys -> Add key -> paste the content of `id_rsa.pub` (in step1) to the key option -> Add key.

   [image]
3. **Generate SSH key in work machine**

   In work machine, execute ssh-keygen command. And it will generate ssh key in your local machine. Paste the content of the public key `id_rsa.pub` to add it in bitbucket (as step4 shows).
4. **Add the SSH key from work machine to bitbucket**

   Click Add key in SSH key Hub of the bitbucket, and then paste the conent of `id_rsa.pub` (in step3).

Now connect bitbucket repo with both home machine and work machine can be accessed.

---

If you still can not access to bitbucket repo vis ssh key, please troubleshooting by the command `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org`.

Details, you can refer the document [Permission denied (publickey)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html).

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly the procedure I'm using and its not working properly :/

Comment: First ,please make sure ssh keys from the two machines are both added in bitbucket. Then you can test the connection by the command `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org` (I updated in the end of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you're adding the 2nd key, you're not affecting the 1st. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-additional-ssh-keys-271943168.html

If you can't make bit bucket work with 2 keys, you can use the same key on both machines. Just copy the `~/.ssh` directory from whichever machine currently works to the other.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly is the docs page I was using, but how could I affect the other key? Don't I have to just add another key to the list in my settings page? So how could this change any data from the first key? The copy-option actually seems like a possible solution! I will try this, when I have access to my work machine again! I'll post the results here.

Comment: So your method works of course, but It might not be a good idea to share one key with multiple machines. When you want to revoke a certain machine you can't when using just one key. Either way my issue now is that both machines clear the ssh-key list after restart (see comment on top).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across that issue or similar, please note that from OS X Monterey (v12.0) and above, the `-K` and `-A` flags of the `ssh-add` command have been deprecated and have been replaced by the `--apple-use-keychain` and `--apple-load-keychain` flags, respectively.

So after creating your key, use `ssh-add ~/.ssh/yourKey --apple-use-keychain` to add the key to your keychain and then call `ssh-add --apple-load-keychain` to load it.

Comment: Trying `ssh-add --apple-load-keychain` results in "ssh-add: illegal option -- -"

Comment: @FuadKamal This error means your version of ssh-add does not support macOS keychain integration, see: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-ssh-add-illegal-option----apple-use-keychain